# Make multi line with line break in a cell in react-data-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-grid

I am using react-data-grid for editing data. Some of data are too long to display in a cell. However, I don't know how to make long data multi line. Also, my data has line break like ↵, but I think react-data-grid ignore this so display the data in one line in a cell.

I hope to find the data in multi line with line break in a cell in react-data-grid